# pesticide spraying on planes, on landing or take off

Tags: uk

I recently saw that on landing in UK from a 3rd world country a [spray](https://www.cntraveler.com/stories/2016-02-19/why-flight-attendants-walk-airplane-aisles-with-bug-spray) was done in the plane on before the landing. My question is not why it is done, but on timing of it.

If UK is worried about [germs](https://www.who.int/ith/mode_of_travel/aircraft_disinsection/en/) coming from a 3rd world country, should not this spray happen before the take off from the 3rd world country ?

Comment: Probably because it is logistically easier to do it locally than having to ship disinfectant to many airports around the world.

Comment: They do have to ship disinfectants (or more likely just bring them with them on the plane), since they spray on the plane before it lands.

Comment: I remember flying from Brazil to Portugal and the spray was done before the plane left Brazil. It may be down to the airline to choose when this is done, or some countries may have specific requirements. I imagine once it is done while the cabin is sealed that is is effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [WHO link](https://www.who.int/ith/mode_of_travel/aircraft_disinsection/en/) you added lists different methods of insecticide application:

> The different procedures currently in use are as follows:
>
> - treatment of the interior of the aircraft using a quick-acting insecticide spray immediately before take-off, with the passengers on board;
> - treatment of the interior of the aircraft on the ground before passengers come on board, using a residual-insecticide aerosol, plus additional in-flight treatment with a quick-acting spray shortly before landing; and
> - regular application of a residual insecticide to all internal surfaces of the aircraft, except those in food preparation areas.

It sounds like the process followed on your flight was the second one, and the spray you saw was the in-flight treatment before landing. The recommended procedures for this are described further in [this report](https://apps.who.int/iris/bitstream/handle/10665/279702/WHO-CDS-NTD-VEM-2018.07-eng.pdf) (for example, it notes that the overhead bins must remain open, which is not generally followed in my experience). Most of the flights I've taken where insecticide was used have used the first process.

[The US Department of Transportation](https://www.transportation.gov/airconsumer/spray) lists disinsection as voluntary for flights to the UK (it's unclear to me if the voluntary nature is true for both malarial countries or just Zika countries, and I couldn't find a UK government source), so it may be up to the airline what method to use.